# Student grades program

Tags: java, beginner, array

I am just looking for code review and overall critique. I want to know what I can do better and how can I do things more efficiently in Java.

I need particular feedback on the use of my `ArrayList` in my `colsToRows` method and then how I converted it back to regular arrays in Java. What better step could I have taken there?

```
/*
double[][] studentScores ={{90,85,75,85,95},
{85,60,65,95,65},
{75,70,80,85,90},
{95,70,75,80,100},
{75,45,80,60,70}};
String[] studentNames = {"Jakob Baloski",
"Lucinda Pavlov",
"Daniele Hanston",
"Yusef Goldstein",
"Leona Rhee"
};
Your app is going to generate the following output to the console:
Jakob Baloski
Highest Score = 95.0
Lowest Score = 75.0
Mean = 86.0 Grade:B
Mean (lowest dropped) = 88.75
-------------------------------------
Lucinda Pavlov
Highest Score = 95.0
Lowest Score = 60.0
Mean = 74.0 Grade:C
Mean (lowest dropped) = 77.5
-------------------------------------
Daniele Hanston
Highest Score = 90.0
Lowest Score = 70.0
Mean = 80.0 Grade:B
Mean (lowest dropped) = 82.5
-------------------------------------
Yusef Goldstein
Highest Score = 100.0
Lowest Score = 70.0
Mean = 84.0 Grade:B
Mean (lowest dropped) = 87.5
-------------------------------------
Leona Rhee
Highest Score = 80.0
Lowest Score = 45.0
Mean = 66.0 Grade:D
Mean (lowest dropped) = 71.25
-------------------------------------
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Assignment  1
Highest Score = 95.0
Lowest Score = 75.0
Mean = 84.0 Grade:B
Mean (lowest dropped) = 86.25
-------------------------------------
Assignment  2
Highest Score = 85.0
Lowest Score = 45.0
Mean = 66.0 Grade:D
Mean (lowest dropped) = 71.25
-------------------------------------
Assignment 3
Highest Score = 80.0
Lowest Score = 65.0
Mean = 75.0 Grade:C
Mean (lowest dropped) = 77.5
-------------------------------------
Assignment 4
Highest Score = 95.0
Lowest Score = 60.0
Mean = 81.0 Grade:B
Mean (lowest dropped) = 86.25
-------------------------------------
Assignment 5
Highest Score = 100.0
Lowest Score = 65.0
Mean = 84.0 Grade:B
Mean (lowest dropped) = 88.75
-------------------------------------
 */



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] studentScores = {
                {90, 85, 75, 85, 95},
                {85, 60, 65, 95, 65},
                {75, 70, 80, 85, 90},
                {95, 70, 75, 80, 100},
                {75, 45, 80, 60, 70}
        };

        String[] studentNames = {
                "Jakob Baloski",
                "Lucinda Pavlov",
                "Daniele Hanston",
                "Yusef Goldstein",
                "Leona Rhee"
        };
        List<List<Double>> assignmentScores = colsToRows(studentScores);

        // PRINT STUDENT RESULTS
        int i = 0;
        for(double[] score : studentScores) {
            System.out.println(studentNames[i]);
            System.out.println("Highest score = " + max(score));
            System.out.println("Lowest score = " + min(score));
            System.out.println("Mean = " + mean(score) + " Grade:" + gradeLetter(mean(score)));
            System.out.println("Mean (lowest dropped) = " + meanLowDrop(score));
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // PRINT ASSIGNMENT RESULTS
        int j = 1;
        for (List<Double> aScore : assignmentScores) {
            // converting from List<Double> to double[]
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018267/how-to-cast-from-listdouble-to-double-in-java
            double[] row = aScore.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();  // converting to a normal array.
            System.out.println("Assignment: " + j);
            System.out.println("Highest score = " + max(row));
            System.out.println("Lowest score = " + min(row));
            System.out.println("Mean = " + mean(row) + " Grade:" + gradeLetter(mean(row)));
            System.out.println("Mean (lowest dropped) = " + meanLowDrop(row));
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            j++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * get the largest number from an array of numbers.
     * @param numbers array.
     * @return double.
     */
    public static double max(double[] numbers) {
        double result = numbers[0];
        for (double number : numbers) {
            if (number > result) {
                result = number;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * get the smallest number from an array of numbers.
     * @param numbers array.
     * @return double.
     */
    public static double min(double[] numbers) {
        double result = numbers[0];
        for (double number : numbers) {
            if (number < result) {
                result = number;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * get the mean of all the numbers in the array.
     * @param numbers array.
     * @return double.
     */
    public static double mean(double[] numbers) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (double number : numbers) {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum / numbers.length;
    }

    public static double meanLowDrop(double[] numbers) {
        double lowestGrade = min(numbers);
        double sum = 0;
        for (double number : numbers) {
            sum += number;
        }
        return (sum - lowestGrade) / (numbers.length - 1);
    }

    /**
     * return a grade letter based on the student's mean grade.
     * @param mean double.
     * @return char.
     */
    public static char gradeLetter(double mean) {
        char result;
        if (mean >= 90) {
            result = 'A';
        } else if (mean >= 80) {
            result = 'B';
        } else if (mean >= 70) {
            result = 'C';
        } else if (mean >= 65) {
            result = 'D';
        } else {
            result = 'F';
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * access columns of a 2d array and return them as rows in an array.
     * @param studentGrades 2d array
     * @return array
     */
    public static List<List<Double>> colsToRows(double[][] studentGrades) {
        List<List<Double>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < studentGrades.length; i++) {
            List<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (double[] studentGrade : studentGrades) {
                temp.add(studentGrade[i]);
            }
            rows.add(temp);
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return 'A';` etc. in `gradeLetter` rather than setting up a variable to return at the end?

Comment: One of my coding buddies told me once that the code is more readable generally when it simply has one return statement.

Comment: I guess it's an opinion which is better, I like that there's less lines and since all the different conditions would look so similar I'd find it readable. But I don't know of any actual benefit apart from it being more readable (to me).

Comment: Yeah i could see that. What you are saying makes sense. By the way for my grade letter method... Should I put the if and else if statements logic one line or leave it as is? Which is more idiomatic in Java?

Comment: If you mean having `if (mean >= 90) { result = 'A'; }` all on one line then I'd definitely leave it as is. It's almost never a good idea to put condition and code block on one line like that.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'll change my result variable to return statements. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make my method documentation better?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need particular feedback on the use of my ArrayList in my colsToRows method and then how I converted it back to regular arrays in Java. What better step could I have taken there?

The better step could be to just stick with either arrays or `ArrayList`, if that's feasible. Converting between them is adding complexity to your code. If `studentScores` was defined as `List<List<Double>>`, you could use the existing `Collections.max` and `.min` methods:

```
for (List<Double> scores : studentScores) {
    ...
    System.out.println("Highest score = " + Collections.max(scores));
    ...
}
```

---

Ignoring that though, your code is quite clean and readable.

Your `max` and `min` methods are perfectly idiomatic, although you may want to check that the array passed into them has `.length > 0` before attempting to access index 0.

Defining a `sum` method could help reduce code duplicated between `mean` and `meanLowDrop`. You may also want to handle the case of empty arrays or of `meanLowDrop` receiving an array of size 1:

```
public static double mean(double[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot take mean of empty array.");
    }
    return sum(numbers) / numbers.length;
}

public static double meanLowDrop(double[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot take mean of empty array.");
    } else if (numbers.length == 1) {
        return mean(numbers);
    }
    return (sum(numbers) - min(numbers)) / (numbers.length - 1);
}
```

I might also rename `meanLowDrop` to `meanDropLowest` or `meanWithoutLowest`.

`gradeLetter` is perfect.

You could rewrite `colsToRows` to directly return a `double[][]` instead of a `List<List<Double>>`, to avoid the dance with `.stream().mapToDouble...` that you're currently doing when printing:

```
public static double[][] colsToRows(double[][] arr) {
    double[][] transposed = new double[arr.length][arr[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            transposed[i][j] = arr[j][i];
        }
    }
    return transposed;
}
```

And as one last point, moving most of `main` into a separate method that looks something like this:

```
public static printStats(double[][] studentScores, String[] studentNames)
```

would make it easier to reuse your code with different students, to run tests, and so on.

Comment: What if max was not built in to collections? Like my mean or my lowest grade dropped function? Then how do I avoid the code complexity as you mentioned of converting from list double to double []?

Comment: @Rafeh I just meant that there are two options - make everything lists (you can use `Collections.max/min` and your `mean`, etc would be written to take `List`) or use only arrays, like you've done, in which case `colsToRows` should be rewritten to return an array instead of a List. If everything else is `double[][]`, then `colsToRows` returning a `List` is the only thing adding complexity.

Comment: Ah this is perfect! This makes a lot of sense! Transposed method returning a regular double[] was exactly what I needed in order to reduce the code complexity. I have also added the printStats method now. I really appreciate this, this is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

#### Input validation

While I agree with [@BenC](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/92493/benc) that the `mean` and `meanLowDrop` methods need some protection against empty array parameters, this check should be at a higher level, for example in this method:

```
public static printStats(double[][] studentScores, String[] studentNames) {
    if (studentScores.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student scores must not be empty.");
    }
    // ...
```

In the same method, another check is due:

```
    if (studentScores.length == studentNames.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There must be the same number of student scores and student names.");
    }
```

#### Aggregate easier using Java 8

Java 8 makes it easier to calculate aggregates, for example:

```
// max
return DoubleStream.of(numbers).max().getAsDouble();

// sum
return DoubleStream.of(numbers).sum();
```

... and so on, you get the idea.